# discord.py commands aren't working (no errors given)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

(Code below is just for entertaining purposes only. Do not use this in discord servers). I honestly have no clue why it isn't working. When I open a new python file with the exact same code, it works. However if I put it in my file with all the code it doesn't for some reason. No output, no errors.

```
from discord.ext import commands

#Settings
KICK_ON_MESSAGE = False

TOKEN = "Token goes here"


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if KICK_ON_MESSAGE == True:
        member = message.author
        await member.kick()
        print(str(member)+' has been succesfully kicked!')


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hi!')



client.run(TOKEN)



Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Please [edit] to show how you are doing this: "*put it in my file with all the code*". Maybe you are not importing the right modules or calling the right functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because you didn't process the commands at the `on_message` event.
Simply add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the `on_message` event (outside the if statement) and it should start working.

Read this for reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working